# Using a ListSelectionModel, how do I get the value of a specific cell when a row is selected?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my Java GUI, I have a table which displays various rows of data. I want the functionality of this to be so that the user clicks on a row and then clicks a button do delete the row (this part works)

Behind the scenes, I need to get the Item ID cell for the selected row, so that I can update my database (using MySQL).

I am still looking through the documentation found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Here is the code I am using to create the table. You can select the rows, and the row index is printed out. I assume this index will be used to access the specific cell I need to also print out the number in the Item ID cell for the current selected row:

````
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import java.awt.Color;

public class App {

    private static JTable loanedItemsTable;
    private static JScrollPane tableScroll;
    private static DefaultTableModel model;
    private static int selectedRow;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("table");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        

        //Items on loan table

        String loanTableColumns [] = {

            "item ID",
            "Item Loaned",
            "Loan Start Date",
            "Return Date",
            "State",
            "Fee to pay",
            "Customer Name"
        };

        String loanTableData [] [] = {

            {"1"},
            {"2"} 
        }
        
        ;

        // adding loan table using a sroll pane

        model = new DefaultTableModel(loanTableData, loanTableColumns);
        
        loanedItemsTable = new JTable(model){
        public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, java.util.EventObject e) {
            return false;
         }
        };

        tableScroll = new JScrollPane(loanedItemsTable);
        tableScroll.setBounds(30, 60, 740, 400);
        panel.add(tableScroll);

        ListSelectionModel model = loanedItemsTable.getSelectionModel();
        model.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                
                if(! model.isSelectionEmpty()){
                    selectedRow = model.getMinSelectionIndex();

                    System.out.println(selectedRow);
                }
            }
            
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Setting aside some bad practices in your code, including using null layouts and over-use of static fields and such, your default table model creation seems in error. You are passing in an array with 7 column names but your data rows only have one data item per row. How can this work?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - This is my first ever Java project so, I apologize for the bad practices. I ran the code and the table is created just fine, all the columns are blank except for the Item ID columns, which are the only ones I am interested in.

Comment: But where are you putting in the real data into the JTable though? I'm confused by this code and your question as it seems incomplete. Is this your entire code? If not, can you instead consider creating and posting a viable [mre] code post with your question?

Comment: You need to make use of both the "row" and "column" selection models or make use of [`JTable#getSelectedColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedColumn()); [`JTable#getSelectedColumns`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedColumns()); [`JTable#getSelectedRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow());

Comment: [`JTable#getSelectedRows`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows()) or just use [`JTable#getValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt(int,int)); much of which is demonstrated at [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` is a bad idea; `frame.setSize(800,600);` should be avoid in favour of `pack`; `tableScroll.setBounds(30, 60, 740, 400);` is unadvisable, see the first point and instead make use of [Appropriate layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Thanks a lot! I think i was a bit stuck because i used the same variable for both model types, so i changed that and go access to the default model functions which you mentioned. All works now

Answer (score 0):

I made sure to change `model` variable for `ListSelectionModel` to a different name (`model2`).

Then I used the `model.getValueAt(rowInt, columnInt)`

This code now prints out the row index as well as the value from the cell in the first column where the selection is made by the user:

````
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
    
    import java.awt.Color;
    
    public class App {
    
        private static JTable loanedItemsTable;
        private static JScrollPane tableScroll;
        private static DefaultTableModel model;
        private static int selectedRow;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
            frame.setSize(800,600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("table");
            frame.setResizable(false);
            
            panel.setLayout(null);
            panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
            
            frame.add(panel);
            
    
            //Items on loan table
    
            String loanTableColumns [] = {
    
                "item ID",
                "Item Loaned",
                "Loan Start Date",
                "Return Date",
                "State",
                "Fee to pay",
                "Customer Name"
            };
    
            String loanTableData [] [] = {
    
                {"1"},
                {"2"} 
            }
            
            ;
    
            // adding loan table using a sroll pane
    
            model = new DefaultTableModel(loanTableData, loanTableColumns);
            
            loanedItemsTable = new JTable(model){
            public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, java.util.EventObject e) {
                return false;
             }
            };
    
            tableScroll = new JScrollPane(loanedItemsTable);
            tableScroll.setBounds(30, 60, 740, 400);
            panel.add(tableScroll);
    
            ListSelectionModel model2 = loanedItemsTable.getSelectionModel();
            model2.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    
                    if(! model2.isSelectionEmpty()){
                        selectedRow = model2.getMinSelectionIndex();
                        String selectedCell = model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0).toString();
                        System.out.println("The row selected is at index: "+selectedRow+" and the item ID is "+selectedCell);
                        
                        
                    }
                }
                
            });
    
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    } ```
````